# C# VSTO Datatable SetField

Tags: c#, datatable

I am trying to create a function to change the value in a datatable. See below for a simplified view:

```
public static void Heading1(DataTable TOC, Excel.Worksheet sheet, Excel.Range cell)
{
       TOC.Rows[1].SetField<string>(5,cell.Value2.ToString());
}
```

But C# returns an error with :

> System.Data.DataRow' has no applicable method named 'SetField' but
>   appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods
>   cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic
>   arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method
>   syntax.

However, if I declare a string and assign the cell value to it, it works fine:

```
public static void Heading1(DataTable TOC, Excel.Worksheet sheet, Excel.Range cell)
{
       string s = cell.Value2;
       TOC.Rows[1].SetField<string>(5,s);
}
```

Is there anyway around this?

Comment: It worked fine in my test.   What is the exact error message?

Comment: The error message was `'System.Data.DataRow' has no applicable method named 'SetField' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.` The string I am trying to insert is a Excel cell value eg. cell.value2 using VSTO.

Comment: In your original question, the value to be set is a string.  Now you say you are trying to insert an Excel cell value.   It may or may not be a string.  If you can't communicate your problem accurately, you're going to waste the time of the people trying to help  you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the column index is 5

```
datatable.Rows[1][5] = "Blah";
```

Be aware if you are doing this you need to have **2 records** in the datable. **If the table have one row and you want to change the value in it, the row index should be 0- > `datatable.Rows[0][5] = "Blah";`**